# Create a String Array in constructor and use it in main function

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to hashing so i wanted to create a hashtable with an array of strings. It is working in the class itself, but when i try to use the array of strings outside of the class it's crashing.
Something is weird with my constructor or the array i think.

I put the Code from the main.cpp and pasted it into the constructor and it was working w/o problems. The console could display my array. But when i try to use the getArray function in main.cpp its crashing.

hashtable.h

```cpp
class hashtable
{
    public:
        hashtable();
        void remove(string);
        int hashfunction(string str);
        string* getArray();
    private:
         int table_size;
         string* T;
};
```

hashtable.cpp

```cpp
hashtable::hashtable()
{
    int table_size = 10;
    elemts_in_array = 0;
    string array[10];

// Im adding some elements to test it. In final Version i will delete the next two lines.
    array[0]="start";
    array[9]="end";

    T = array;

// now I am testing if my function string* getArray() is working, and it's working when i dont use it in main.cpp

    string* arraytest = getArray();
     for (int i=0; i< 10;i++)
     {
         cout << i << " - " << arraytest[i]<< endl;
     }
}


/////////// getArray function
string* hashtable::getArray()
{
    return T;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
int main()
{
    hashtable table;
    string* array = table.getArray();
    for (int i=0; i< 10;i++)
    {
        cout << i << " - " << array[i]<< endl;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When i only create an Object called hashtable, its working without any problems, but when i am creating an object and i want to give the array over my getArray function to main.cpp its crashing and i really dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` goes out of scope at the end of `hashtable`'s constructor and leaves `T` pointing to invalid memory.  If you want the array pointed to by `T` to continue to exist outside the scope of `hashtable`'s constructor, you'll need dynamic allocation.  Or better yet, use `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
class hashtable
{
    public:
        hashtable()
            : T{10}
        {
            T[0] = "start";
            T[T.size() - 1] = "end";

            for (int i = 0; i < T.size(); ++i)
            {
                std::cout << i << " - " << T[i] << '\n';
            }
        }

        std::vector<std::string>& getArray()
        {
            return T;
        }

        void remove(std::string);
        int hashfunction(std::string str);

    private:
        std::vector<std::string> T;
};

int main()
{
    hashtable table;
    std::vector<std::string>& array = table.getArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " - " << array[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bfa998ae25840a1)